# Don't know the necessary LinkedIn permission to post jobs

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I have done OAuth and have a token.
I have 4 scopes for my token:

- openid
- profile
- w_member_social
- email

But when I try to make a post request to
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/simpleJobPostings`, using python

```
import requests
import json

with open('response.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

access_token = data.get('access_token', 'No token')

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/simpleJobPostings'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'x-restli-method': 'batch_create'
}

body ={
 "elements": [{
   "integrationContext": "urn:li:organization:my_code_was_here",
   "companyApplyUrl": "http://linkedin.com",
   "description": "We are looking for a passionate Software Engineer to design, develop and install software solutions. Software Engineer responsibilities include gathering user requirements, defining system functionality and writing code in various languages. Our ideal candidates are familiar with the software development life cycle (SDLC) from preliminary system analysis to tests and deployment.",
   "employmentStatus": "PART_TIME",
   "externalJobPostingId": "1234",
   "listedAt": 1440716666,
   "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
   "title": "Software Engineer",
   "location": "India",
   "workplaceTypes": [
    "remote"
   ]
  } 
  ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
response.raise_for_status()  # This will raise an HTTPError if the request fails
```

This is the basic template that the LinkedIn documentation has. But If I try to make the request I get:

```
esktop/LinkedInOAuth/post_jobs.py
403
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: POST /simpleJobPostings","status":403}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\LinkedInOAuth\post_jobs.py", line 37, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()  # This will raise an HTTPError if the request fails
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/simpleJobPostings
```

This is what I have found in the documentation:

403 403 Not enough permissions to access: POST (Name)

Access token is generated from the application which does not have permission to access this resource   .

Use Partner application for creating child application, all other resources should be requested using child applications.